# failed to resolve all the libraries in my dependency

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I just delete my .gradle/caches folder and redownload all library again for some reason and after download finished I just do clean and rebuild, but now gradle can't build and all libraries get failed to resolve error. I bring my .gradle/caches back to first time but no changes. I tried invalidate cach or gradle  offline work but not fixed. this happened to all projects

please help.thanks

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dibapc.alopackage"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "xxxx",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.myinnos:ImageSliderWithSwipes:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4"
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:runtime-permission:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please post your gradle dependencies

Comment: @mzeus.bolt post updated

Comment: Can you please post you project's gradle file and the complete messages ?

Comment: @rgv all the messages is failed to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `implementation` from now on instead of `compile`. i.e:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Second, if you deleted the caches, it will need to download everything again so, in your case changing your IP will solve and then do clean-project and **uncheck** `Offline work` to download the needed files from the internet.

If this didn't help, try add these to your `build.gradle` repositories:

```
 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
```

At the end, update your `gradle` to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Comment: Change the repositories like pasted by mine in the answer. Then, change your IP since it (Iran's IP) is blocked then, make sure you haven't check the Offline Work then, rebuild-project should help.